# How can we (in the Call Hierarchy window) view Calls From in Visual Studio for C#/VB.NET code not just C++

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Visual Studio has a very handy Call Hierarchy window, but only for C++ does it show the Calls From a member, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/call-hierarchy?view=vs-2022).

[image]

Is there a way, maybe with a free VS Extension, to also see the Calls From for C#/VB.NET code?

I see that NDepend does something like this (and makes a diagram of it, very cool) but NDepend is way too much functionality to add (and cost) for such a simple need.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Works for me with VB in VS 2019, no additional add-ins installed.  I right-clicked on a VB function, selected "View Call Hierarchy", and it showed all calls (all of them from VB code) in the window.

Comment: I only get Calls To and not Calls From with VB.NET and that is also what VS documentation says, so I think an extension is needed to get this functionality.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Yes, I have calls to but not calls from.